# is not a number in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created this code to check if value is number or not but it doesn't seem to work.

```
app.controller('ForCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.calcul_factorielle = function() {

        var mm = 1;
        if ((typeof ($scope.test) !== 'number')) $scope.factorielle = " invalide saisie";

        for(i=2;i<=$scope.test;i++) {
            mm = mm * i;
        }
        $scope.factorielle = mm;
    }
});
```

Why, when I'm entering string `stackoverflow` am I not receiving the `'invalide saisie'` message in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this `if` statement, if your text is not a number, you need to break the execution of the function with the keyword `return`. In your case the code continues after the `if` statement, so you get a wrong result.

For first you need to parse it into `number`, because every input is a `string` and after that then try to use `isNaN()` function. If string can not be parsed to the `number` it will return an `NaN`.

```
var number = Number.parseInt($scope.test);
if (isNaN(number)) { // or i
       $scope.factorielle = " invalide saisie";
       return;
}
```

Comment: I modifier my code with your code but I haven't any result , and when i entering a number value i haven't any result also

Comment: okey now when i entering a number value i have message invalid saisie :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the if statement, apply [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) before `typeof` operator, so replace:

```
typeof ($scope.test) !== 'number'
```

To:

```
(typeof (parseFloat($scope.test)) !== 'number')
```

Comment: Thank you to all to be of help me